# Delete an object in an ng-repeat without affecting other similar objects

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a form that is constructing a program, each program has weeks and each week has days it is currently being constructed as demonstrated in this pen http://codepen.io/Irish1/pen/lbjdw

and the code, with the inputs removed for brevity

*html*

```
        <button type ="button" ng-click="addWeek()"> add week</button>

        <div ng-repeat="week in program.weeks">
         <p>a week</p>

            <div ng-repeat="day in week.days">
                <p> a day</p>
            </div>
            <button type ="button" ng-click="addDay($index)"> Add Day</button>
            <button type ="button" ng-click="remove($index)"> Remove week</button>
        </div>

        <button type="submit"> add program</button>
    </form>
 </div>

</div>
```

*app.js*

```
var myModule = angular.module("trainercompare", ['ui.bootstrap']);

function programsController($scope, $http) {

    var numweeks = 1;
    $scope.program = { 

    };

    $scope.addWeek = function() {

        if (isDefined($scope.program.weeks)) {
            $scope.program.weeks.push(
                {

                }
            );

        } else {
            $scope.program = { 
                weeks: [
                    {

                    }
                ]
            };
        }
    };

    $scope.addDay = function(index) {

        if (isDefined($scope.program.weeks[index].days)) {
            $scope.program.weeks[index].days.push(
                {

                }
            );

        } else {
            $scope.program.weeks[index] = { 
                days: [
                    {

                    }
                ]
            };
        }
    };

    $scope.remove = function(index) {
        $scope.program.weeks.splice(index, 1);

        console.log(index);

    };

    function isDefined(x) {

    return x !== undefined;
    }

    $scope.addProgram = function() {

        console.log($scope.program);

        $http.post('/programs', $scope.program).success(function(data, status) {
            if(isDefined(data.errors)) {
                console.log(data.errors);
                $scope.errors = data.errors;
                }
            if(isDefined(data.success)) {
                console.log(data.success);
                $scope.errors = [];
            }
        });

    }; 


}
```

I want to be able to delete any day that is added to a week without affecting days in other weeks that may have the same index I think I need to do something like this

```
$scope.program.weeks[1].days.splice(index, 1);
```

but I dont know how to access the weeks index from within the ng-repeat='day in days'

I would also like to modify the current remove method shown above so that it can be used for removing either a week or a day or anything else that gets added to the object in the future but I dont know how to pass it the correct array  it should be removing the object from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is better than Jason's or not, but this is how I normally do it.

I use an `ng-init` to store the `$index` to a scope variable so that if there's other `$scopes` in between the inner and outer `ng-repeat`'s You don't have to add more `$parent`'s (maybe that's not possible somehow, but this is what I've done anyway).

http://plnkr.co/edit/DH8MP8i65UAjq8oLBtnX?p=preview

Relevant code from Plunkr:

**Controller:**

```
$scope.outer = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5]
];
```

**Template:**

```
<div ng-repeat="o in outer" ng-init="oIndex = $index">
  <div ng-repeat="i in o" ng-init="iIndex = $index">outer[{{oIndex}}][{{iIndex}}] == {{ outer[oIndex][iIndex]}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the $parent.$index which would give you the weeks index.

Your remove method could maybe look something like...

```
$scope.remove = function(parentIndex, index) {
        $scope.program.weeks[parentIndex].splice(index, 1);
        $scope.apply();    
    };
```

Comment: Man it is amazing how easy that is, I am really starting to love angular.  any advice on the remove method?

Comment: thanks for the remove method, I am trying to get it to work no matter how many objects there are for example days is going to have a number of sessions and each session is going to have a number of phases all of which need to be added and removed like weeks and days can be so thats the type of remove method I am going for.

Comment: The apply was just to force the scope objects to update; more for safety sake than anything else. It shouldn't be needed.